# Getting closed_login_failed in facebook login android when I enter another facebook address

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated facebook login with my android application and I am successfully able to log in (and fetch user info) with my facebook email address (I have installed the native facebook application).
However, when I log in with another valid email address (in the facebook native application), I get closed_login_failed in Session.StatusCallback callback in my application.

Comment: I solved the problem by enabling 
Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? to yes in the facebook developer site.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by enabling Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? to yes in the facebook developer site.